# How to remove additional row with mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

I am using Winforms and filling up my `datagridview` with `SQL database` values. These values are user defined values from a different form during runtime. I will keep compiling these values hence, I've used `visibleChanged` instead of `load` to display my data.

The data are compiling correctly but after loading the second set of values onwards, additional empty rows are being compiled too (See image).

[image]

How do I remove these additional rows?

Below is my code on how I load the values from `database` to datagridview:

```
public Testsql()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 100;
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 100;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "ID";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "EXTERIOR";

        dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    }

private void Testsql_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
        sqlConnection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Savertb.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
        sqlCommand.CommandText = "Select * from Rtbdata";

        SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

            for (int i = 0; dataReader.Read(); i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ID"].Value = dataReader["Id"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["EXTERIOR"].Value = dataReader["Exterior"].ToString();
            }

        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You should bind your datagrid view to a datatable and use a dataadapter to clear and refill the table with updated data

Comment: @Caius Jard Ahhh great. There are no additional rows after following your recommendation. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I was not able reproduce your environment but i think below shall work

1) copy all datagrid row to datatable object

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = ((DataView)DataGrid1.ItemsSource).ToTable();
```

2) then remove empty row in DataTable ( if exists)
[How to remove empty rows from DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023140/how-to-remove-empty-rows-from-datatable)

3) Finally copy back all datatable row and overwrite DataGrid1 object

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: It's a very roundabout way of violating MVC principles! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's slightly wasteful to fill a new datatable all the time, but it makes the code simpler:

```
//sqlstr is your SELECT.. connatr isnthe connection string
var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, connStr);
var dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt); //dataadapter will open and close conn for you
gridview.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete empty rows in your Table use:

```
DELETE FROM Rtbdata WHERE [EXTERIOR] IS NULL AND [ID] IS NULL
```

Using the AND operator to not delete Rows where exterior OR id contains one value

If you only don't want to show them use:

```
SELECT * FROM Rtbdata WHERE [EXTERIOR] IS NOT NULL AND [ID] IS NOT NULL
```

Using the AND Operator to show rows if exterior OR id contains one value

else you can use OR if you don't want either EXTERIOR oder ID to be NULL