# I can't insert my data where I want in Excel

Tags: c#, oledb

I can insert my data to Excel well, but I have a problem.

Here is a [screenshot to illustrate](http://resimag.com/p1/e9c056dbd58.png).

I want to see my inserted data just below the last inserted data, but it shows up further down, in the screenshot as shown with a black circle.

Here is my code:

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelfilepath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;ReadOnly=False;HDR=Yes;\"";

OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("insert into [EVDS$] ([Tarih], [USD], [EUR]) values('" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "')", connection);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: Are you concerned about the blank rows? It seems that you inserted blank rows at some point. If you highlight all the blank rows, delete and try to insert again, i would think that would fix the issue.

Comment: You must of deleted rows for this to occur.  The insert is writing to the end of the "Used Area" in Excel. When you delete a row of excel the used area does not shrink.

Comment: Similar to [How to remove empty rows from DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023140/how-to-remove-empty-rows-from-datatable)