# C# reading excel and still getting data from blank cells

Tags: c#, excel

I have a tool I made for work.  Every week there are 5-20 files for a certain process that fails and I have to find their job ids and rerun them.

I made a tool in C# that takes the names of the failed files in an Excel spreadsheet (we'll call it the Failed File Spreadsheet, or FFS if you're feeling cynical) and then cross references them with a different Excel spreadsheet that has the job ids, and displays the result in the terminal.  It reads the FFS this with a fairly simple `OledDbDataAdapter` code:

```
public static DataTable GetDataFromExcel(string filename, string sheetName)
{
    using(var oledb = new OleDbConnection(CONN_STR.Replace("<FILENAME>", filename).Replace("<HDR>", "no"))
    {
         var result = new DataSet();
         new OleDbDataAdapter($"SELECT * FROM [{sheetName}]", oledb).Fill(result);
         return result.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

The tool works fine, mostly.  It cross references with another excel sheet and I get my job ids and I can carry on with my task.

However there's one slight issue, and that is that, often when running the tool, when it reads from the FFS, sometimes it returns blank lines.  Like if last week I had 7 files, then this week I erased those, pasted in 5 files, then my tool will show the job ids for those 5 files just fine, but also show two blanks, as if it's still reading those two extra rows from the previous week.  If however I make a new blank spreadsheet in Excel, plug in my failed files and overwrite the save file, I don't have this issue at all, making me think this is an Excel issue and not a C# coding issue.

Is there a reason why, if I delete the contents of a cell, the OleDbDataAdapter would still be reading those cells?  Like are there whitespace characters or other hidden characters still present after deleting contents?  I mean I could fix it in the code and just say "don't write it out if the values are whitespace or null" but I want to know why blank cells are even being read at all.

This is just a minor bug and it's not stopping me from doing my work and this tool is nothing more than a personal tool to help with a weekly task.  But I'd still like to know why cells that had content, but then had that content deleted, are still being read.

Answer (score 0):

Excel is a little bit quirky like that.  If you are manually editing your "Failed File Spreadsheet" (FFS) and as you say, you are pasting 5 rows over the existing 7 rows, then you may still read in those extra rows after the data you expect, if there is any formatting on the cells. To avoid this, in Excel select the range of cells of the whole sheet and right-click and select "Clear Contents".

To be fair, as you alluded to, I think it would be simpler just to fix it in code and skip rows in the DataTable that are empty.  Or there is a SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41424844/2534378)  which shows how to remove empty rows from a DataTable